# NoMethodError in ContactsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets

I am trying to make a functional contact form that stores data in a Google Drive spreadsheet. 
When I am testing the application, and fill in the contact form and press 'submit', i get this error:

```
NoMethodError in ContactsController#create  
undefined method `login' for GoogleDrive:Module.
```

**Application Trace**

```
app/models/contact.rb:16:in 'update_spreadsheet'  
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :string
  attr_accessor :email, :string
  attr_accessor :content, :string
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_format_of :email,
  :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def update_spreadsheet

    connection = GoogleDrive.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
      Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
      )

    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
      ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end 
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.name
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.email
    ws[last_row, 4] = self.content
    ws.save
  end

end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end  

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(secure_params)
    if @contact.valid?
            @contact.update_spreadsheet
      # TODO send message
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent from #{@contact.name}."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def secure_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue while following the Learn Rails book by Daniel Kehoe. If you check the [GitHub repository for the project](https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails), he has included a simple workaround. Specifically:

In the file **app/models/contact.rb**

```
require "google_drive_v0"
```

And the connection variable:

```
connection = GoogleDriveV0.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password)
```

has been updated from the book. The full code for the file is:

```
require "google_drive_v0"
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :string
  attr_accessor :email, :string
  attr_accessor :content, :string

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDriveV0.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
)
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
      ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.name
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.email
    ws[last_row, 4] = self.content
    ws.save
  end

end
```

This will allow your code to run using the older method, but you will get the following warning in your console:

> WARNING: GoogleDriveV0.login is deprecated and will be removed in the
>   next version. Use GoogleDriveV0.login_with_oauth instead.

To fix this you can follow the helpful information from the other poster. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: `GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth`

```
def update_spreadsheet

  connection = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)
  )
...

end
```

to get an access_token

```
# Authorizes with OAuth and gets an access token.
client = Google::APIClient.new
auth = client.authorization
auth.client_id = "YOUR CLIENT ID"
auth.client_secret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET"
auth.scope =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
auth.redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
print("1. Open this page:\n%s\n\n" % auth.authorization_uri)
print("2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: ")
auth.code = $stdin.gets.chomp
auth.fetch_access_token!
access_token = auth.access_token
```

You can make a second method, like so

Here's an extract related to the issue you're facing.

Ver. 1.0.0 is not 100% backward compatible with 0.3.x. Some methods have been removed. Especially, GoogleDrive.login has been removed, and you must use GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth instead, as in the example code below.

Read more here: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

Update:

You can implement a new file with a new class

Or just add a new method somewhere:

```
def new_access_token
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  ... #excluded some code
  access_token = auth.access_token
  access_token # this line important, returning access_token
end
```

Now you can call pass in it, like so: connection = `GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(new_access_token)`

If you want to create a new class, do something like:

```
Class Token
  def new_access_token
  ...
  end
end
```

Might be cleaner way to do it that way, now you can call it by:

```
token = Token.new
token.new_access_token
```

And pass that in:

`GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(token.new_access_token)`

Its up to you which method you prefer.

Comment: In which file do I need to write the code to get an acces_token?

Comment: see edits, you don't need to create a new file if you don't want to.